# Moving window over repeated registries

Tags: r

I have a database with a column that includes repeated codes, then another column with associated values, e.g.:

```
[code] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7  
[value]2 3 5 9 5 6 7 8 3 4 5 6 7 3 8 9 6 2 3 4 5 6 3 2 5 6 7 8
```

I aim to calculate mean and variance of values taken over a centered moving window. This moving window must consider the 2 previous and 2 next registries to an associated code value, e.g.: For Code value 4, it will be as follows:

```
2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6

5 6 7 8 3 4 5 6 7 3 8 9 6 2 3 4 5 6 3 2 -> Mean and variance for these values
```

Here's a `dput` of `code` and `value` column in a data frame `dat`:

```
structure(list(code = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7), value = c(2, 3, 
5, 9, 5, 6, 7, 8, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 8, 9, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 
2, 5, 6, 7, 8)), .Names = c("code", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 
-28L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: So, I guess for the code `1`, it should take `value` corresponding to 1, 2 & 3 code?

Comment: I forgot to mention that the number of code values with a specific value can vary from 1 to 5, so the moving window size must be variable. e.g.: [Code] 11111223333344455555

Comment: Have you tried the above code?

Comment: Thanks akrun, for the code 1 it should take value 1, 2 & 3, and for 2 should take 1, 2, 3, 4.

Answer (score 1):

One way is:

```
res <-  sapply(unique(dat$code), function(x) {
             x1 <- dat$value[dat$code %in% (x-2):(x+2)]
              c(mean(x1), var(x1))})
res
#        [,1]  [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5] [,6]     [,7]
#[1,] 5.250000 5.625 5.250000 5.100000 5.100000 5.25 4.750000
#[2,] 4.386364 5.050 5.039474 4.305263 4.305263 5.00 3.840909
```

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thank you very much akrun for your help. Best.